# jQuery If statements and variables

Tags: jquery, mask

Basically, I have a top bar that scrolls down when hovered on. I added a top mask layer to make it darker. I want the top mask to be visible when css top value is = -180.

The current problem should be that the variable (css top value) is not updating all the time.

```
$('.topmask').hover(function () {
    $('.topbar').stop().animate({"top":"0px"});
    visible1 = $('.topbar').css('top');
});

$('.topbar').mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({"top":"-180px"});
});

var visible1 = $('.topbar').css('top');;console.log(visible1);
var visible = parseFloat(visible1); 

if (visible = -180) {
    $('.topmask').show();
} else {
    $('.topmask').hide();
}
```

And here's a link to a JSfiddle I quickly did to demonstrate the problem better, as I am obviously bad at explaining. http://jsfiddle.net/Fregos/DyrK5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Animations execute asynchronously, so when you're calculating the `top`, the animation hasn't yet completed. How about showing and hiding the topbar based on a callback fired after the animation is complete?

```
$('.topmask').hover(function () {
    $('.topbar').stop().animate({"top":"0px"}, function() {
        $('.topmask').hide('fade');
    });
});

$('.topbar').mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({"top":"-180px"}, function() {
        $('.topmask').show('fade');
    });
});
```

Working example at http://jsfiddle.net/DyrK5/1/.

Comment: I started with this, but it just doesn't look good, because the top mask is visible when the top bar is already animating.

Comment: That is easy to change by moving the code that hides the top mask. How's [http://jsfiddle.net/DyrK5/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/DyrK5/4/)?

Comment: OK, got it to work with your idea. Thanks dude. lol, I just edited your jsfiddle to this: http://jsfiddle.net/Fregos/6sLN2/ and right after that I read your comment and it was like identical to what I just edited in your code :D Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few problems I see here. First and foremost, you must set the action to either show or hide the mask as a callback of the animation function. Here's what happens when the page first loads for you:

1. If a user hovers on topbar, perform an animation.
2. If a user stops hovering on topbar, perform an animation.
3. If topbar's position is -180px, show the mask. Otherwise, hide it.

What you really want is this:

1. If a user hovers on topbar, perform an animation. At the conclusion of the animation, hide the mask.
2. If a user stops hovering on topbar, perform an animation. At the conclusion of the animation, show the mask.

So either you need to conditionally hide or show the mask within the bound event or within the animation callback. For more information on setting a callback to the animate function, take a look at this: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

The other noticeable glaring error I see is that you are currently setting the value of visible to -180 in your conditional statement.

```
if (visible = -180) { ... }
```

is not the same as:

```
if (visible == -180) { ... }
```

Comment: Whats the difference between = and ==? And where can I learn all of these? I can't find any info about all of these equation things.

Comment: This is extremely important to understanding programming in general. = assigns a value to a variable, == asserts whether the two compared values are generically equal (0 == 0 return true, as does 0 == false), === asserts whether the two compared values are precisely equal (0 === 0 returns true, 0 === false returns false).

Comment: Here's a little something I found on wikipedia that describes it a little more clearly: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_programming)#Assignment_versus_equality

Comment: Thanks, now that I know something about it it should be easier to understand :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do:

```
$('.topmask').hover(function () {
    $('.topbar').stop().animate({"top":"0px"});
    $('.topmask').hide();
});
$('.topbar').mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({"top":"-180px"}, function() {
        $('.topmask').show();
    });
});
```

Comment: I started with that, but it just doesn't look good, because the top mask is visible when the top bar is already animating. And for some reason I can't get delay to work, so that I could just delay the visibility a bit.

Comment: No it doesn't, did you try it?  The top mask is only visible when it's in a closed state, not when it's animating.

Comment: Sorry, just realized. I'm using this now, but it's the same that brandon posted. Thank you for your time dude.